# Store image in database using rails paperclip plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I have an application that uses the Paperclip plugin for image upload. Now that app should get deployed to an host(heroku) which has a read-only file system. Can I somehow tell paperclip to store the images in the database?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out this sample app

http://patshaughnessy.net/2009/5/29/paperclip-sample-app-part-3-saving-file-attachments-in-a-database-blob-column

I guess this is exactly what you need.

HTH

PS: storing images in db is usually a bad idea, I am sure you can use paperclip with S3 / cloudfront ( as mentioned in the answers below )

Answer (score 5):

Heroku recommends storing file uploads on s3, and [provides instructions](http://docs.heroku.com/s3) on how to do so for several Rails file plugins.

Answer (score 4):

Rethink what you're doing. Storing images in the db is generally a bad idea. For more info, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay).

ry is right to point you towards S3. If nothing else, think of the cost: 500 MB of database space on Heroku is $50/month. On S3, it'll be 15 cents.

Answer (score 0):

Image serving from S3 is slow. Latencies of 0.5s to 2s are common, which means it should only be used for media assets.